# Warning: Cannot modify header information

Tags: php, php7, headers

Cuando logro inciciar sesión, no me muestra el contenido del Header y me aparece este mensaje:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output 
started at /storage/ssd3/553/11626553/public_html/php/check-login.php:4) in 
/storage/ssd3/553/11626553/public_html/php/check-login.php on line 57
```

En la línea numero 57 tengo lo siguiente:

```
header('Location: welcome.php');
```

Pero el archivo "welcome.php" lo tengo en otra carpeta y el contenido es el siguiente:

welcome.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <?php
 session_start();
 ?>
 <?php include ('complementos/navroot.php'); ?>
 <header>
 <center>    <img src="images/pdi.jpg"  alt="Responsive image md-3" 
 height="100"><img src="images/cdmx.jpg"  alt="Responsive image md-6" 
 height="100"></center>
</header>
<title>Administrador</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

¿Será que no estoy enlazando bien el archivo "welcome.php" en la línea 57?
debería ser `header('Location: nombredelacarpeta/welcome.php');`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En [Cómo solucionar «Cannot modify header information» en PHP](https://cybmeta.com/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent) se explica que el problema está en "imprimir" algo antes de modificar el header. Aunque sea un espacio, una etiqueta... cualquier cosa cuenta:

> La causa más habitual de este problema es utilizar funciones que dan salida a información, por ejemplo con `print` o con `echo`, y luego intentar modificar las cabeceras, por ejemplo con `header()` o con `setcookie()`, ya que generan la situación descrita: se da salida a información, y esa información lleva sus respectivas cabeceras HTTP; no se pueden modificar después.
>
> Hay que tener en cuenta que dentro de un script PHP, cualquier símbolo que no esté entre las etiquetas `<?php` y `?>` también genera salida. Por ejemplo, un simple espacio antes de `<?php` ya genera salida de información. De hecho, este fallo «tonto» del espacio, u otro símbolo, antes de

Dado que tienes la llamada a `header()` en la línea 57, doy por casi seguro que antes hay algún elemento de este tipo.

La solución es mover este `header()` antes de cualquier elemento que genere salida.

Comment: Gracias me ha ayudado moverlo...